# itunes connect tax for non us companies

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have been trying to fill out the form "tax information" for my company
in itunes connect and got totally stuck.

In the menu navigation, I indicated that my company is not located in
the US and got forwarded to the form "Manage your tax information".
After filling out all required fields and trying to send the form I get
the error message: *"Please specify the type of income"*

It's not clear to me what I am supposed to do here. Regarding "income" I
only get a hint to *Part III: Claim of Tax Treaty Benefits*. But I
dont't think that this is what I actually need to to. If I check the box
*Income from the sale of applications*. I get the error message *Please
make sure to fill out all the required fields correctly.*

I don't know what to do now. I have read the *Instructions for Form
W-8BEN-E*. From my understanding my company should not have to fill out
lines 14 and 15. But if I leave them blank I get *"Please specify the
type of income"*.

Does anybody have an idea what to do here? Any help would be very
appreciated.